# Converting c# byte to java byte

Tags: c#, java, type-conversion, byte, endianness

I'm not realizing what is wrong with my code, take a look:

**C# code:**

```
const int MOVE = 112;
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
m.SetLength(4 + 1 + (1 + 1 + 1 + 1));
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(m);
int id_ = getId();
bw.Write(Converter.GetBigEndian(id_));
sbyte eventMove = MOVE;
sbyte rowFromByte = 4;
sbyte colFromByte = 2;
sbyte rowToByte = 1;
sbyte colToByte = 3;
bw.Write(eventMove);
bw.Write(rowFromByte);
bw.Write(colFromByte);
bw.Write(rowToByte);
bw.Write(colToByte);
```

**When I read on java I do:**

```
ByteBuffer msg = an instance of ByteBuffer...
int id = msg.getInt();
byte event = msg.get();
byte rowFrom = msg.get();
byte colFrom = msg.get();
byte rowTo = msg.get();
byte colTo = msg.get();
```

Every time I read on java it reaches till the event ok.

Sometimes it works correctly, reads everything ok e.g if I put on c#:

```
sbyte rowFromByte = 12;
sbyte colFromByte = 2;
sbyte rowToByte = 1;
sbyte colToByte = 3;
```

It works, but if I put a value <= 7 on the first rowFromByte e.g:

```
sbyte rowFromByte = 4;
sbyte colFromByte = 2;
sbyte rowToByte = 1;
sbyte colToByte = 3;
```

the java code doesn't read the values correctly it reads:

```
rowFrom: -7, colFrom: 0, rowTo: -7, colTo: 0
```

**SOLVED: the values above were printed wrongly (during the wrong time), because of that I thought there were problems with the code.
It prints the corrects values bellow:**

```
 rowFrom: 4, colFrom: 2, rowTo: 1, colTo: 3
```

On c# I use the Memorystream to get the bytes to send to java client:

```
MemoryStream message = the instance of memory stream...
bytesMessage = message.ToArray();
```

WHY putting a value <= 7 for rowFrom returns wrong bytes association on java?

There's something very weird or silly I'm not getting into.

Comment: You may want to specify type of `msg`

Comment: ok, ByteBuffer I already edited.

Comment: How is the stream transmitted to the Java process?  Via the filesystem, netwoek, or something else?

Comment: I transmit via NetworkStream & TcpClient from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The problem is that: **there wasn't any problem with my code**.

As I supposed this was a Silly stuff: I was printing the wrong variables on server.

I didn't know very well C# I posted this question on on stackoverflow.
Maybe this simple example can be useful for other people.