# C# Client and Java Server, transferring UTF-8 Byte Array from c# to Java method

Tags: java, c#, c#-4.0, utf-8, arrays

I have client server application, 
On server I have java service, and on client I am using C#.

following is the Server side, which is Java method

```
  public void onChange(byte[] message)
    {

                DataInputStream datastream=new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(message));
                String msgid=datastream.readUTF(); 
                String typuser=datastream.readUTF(); 
     }
```

now the client side is doing nothing but transfering byte[] to this above function , but while decoding it throw exception

```
malformed input around byte 105
```

the client side code is this

```
     using (MemoryStream requestStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(requestStream))
                {


                   byte[] tempmsgid = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg_id);
                   String msgid;
                   msgid= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempmsgid);


                   byte[] temptypeuser = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(type_user);
                   String typeuser;
                   typeuser = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(temptypeuser)

                   writer.Write(msgid);
                   writer.Write(typeuser);
                   writer.close()
    } 
return requestStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486304/converting-c-sharp-byte-to-java-byte